# how to put number of strings in each label

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script to fetch the list of channels from the sqlite3 database.

I want to fetch 7 channels to set each channel in each label control `4010`, `4011`, `4012`, `4013`, `4014`, `4015` and `4016`. When I fetch the list of channels to put them in each label, nothing really happens as each label control has not set the text.

When I use this:

```
#Pull the data from the database
channelList = list()
programList = list()
database_path = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))

if os.path.exists(database_path):
    #get the channels list
    cur.execute('SELECT channel FROM programs WHERE channel GROUP BY channel')


    for row in cur:
        channel = row[0].encode('ascii')
        channelList.append(channel)

        # set the channels text
        for index in range(0, channels_per_page):
             if index >= len(channel):
                self.setControlLabel(4010 + index, channel)
```

**Result:**

```
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 102 CBS
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 105 ESPN USA
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 106 Fox News
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 107 Animal Planet
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 108 USA Network
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 110 SPIKE
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 111 BRAVO USA
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 112 BRAVO1
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 113 BRAVO2
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 114 BRAVO3
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 115 BRAVO4
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 116 BRAVO5
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 117 BRAVO6
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 118 BRAVO7
```

I want to set the text in each label control like this:

```
>>4010 ABC FAMILY
>>4011 CNN USA
>>4012 ESPN USA
>>4013 Fox News
>>4014 Animal Planet
>>4015 USA Network
>>4016 SPIKE
```

**EDIT: When I use this code:**

```
self.getControl(4110 + idx).setLabel(channels)
```

I get this result:

```
>>4010 BRAVO7
>>4011 BRAVO7
>>4012 BRAVO7
>>4013 BRAVO7
>>4014 BRAVO7
>>4015 BRAVO7
>>4016 BRAVO7
```

EDIT: When I use this:

```
self.getControl(4110 + index).setLabel(channels[index])
```

It will split the string and set each letter to each label control like this:

```
4110 >> 1
4111 >> 0
4112 >> 1
4113 >> 
4114 >> A
4115 >> B
4116 >> C
```

It should be look like this:

```
>>4010 ABC FAMILY
>>4011 CNN USA
>>4012 ESPN USA
>>4013 Fox News
>>4014 Animal Planet
>>4015 USA Network
>>4016 SPIKE
```

Comment: What does `self.setControlLabel()` do? Is all of this code inside a class definition?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense well the `self.setControlLabel()` will set the text using the control id and the variable where i use to get the list of strings. I think it will be easy to use `self.getControl(4110 + idx).setLabel(channels)`, but the trouble is it will set the same text in each control on the end of the string in the array. Please see my update post.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: do you have any idea how i can set the text in each label control from what you saw in my update post?

Comment: Can you tell me the purpose of `if index >= len(channel):`?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I have no idea what the purpose I'm using of `if index >= len(channel):`, so do you know how i can set the text in each label control with each different strings of channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for row in cur:
    channel = row[0].encode('ascii')
    channelList.append(channel)

    # set the channels text
    for index in range(0, channels_per_page):
         if index >= len(channel):
            self.setControlLabel(4010 + index, channel)
```

Here it looks like you're doing the `for` loop once per channel you obtain from the database. I'm guessing that you actually want to run that for loop after you've gotten all the data from the database. If that is the case, this code will probably do the trick:

```
for row in cur:
    channel = row[0].encode('ascii')
    channelList.append(channel)

# set the channels text
for index in range(len(channelList)):
      self.setControlLabel(4010 + index, channelList[index])
```

But it is a little difficult to understand what some of these functions do (`setControlLabel`, `getControl`, `setLabel`) and what you're trying to accomplish with your code. This is my assumption based on the comments.

Comment: thank you very much for this, the function of `setControlLabel` and `getControl.setLabel` is set the text in the label control using the id. So I prefer to use the `getControl.setLabel`.

Comment: do you know how i can set the string in each label control using the array when i fetch the list of channels?

Comment: @user3757279 I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Can you be more clear?

Comment: when I use the `self.getControl(4110 + index).setLabel(channels[index])`, it will split the strings into each letter and set the each letter to each control. i want to set the full string in each control when i fetch the list of channels from sqlite3 database. is that clear? please see my update post.

Comment: @user3757279 my solution had a typo. I replaced `channel[index]` with `channelList[index]`. Try that. Basically, if you try to get the `[index]` of a single channel, it's going to return single characters. You need to get the index of the entire list of channels.

Comment: Thank you, i can see it is nearly working, but i'm getting an error: `IndexError: list index out of range` when i use this code: `for index in range(0, channels_per_page): self.getControl(4110 + index).setLabel(channelList[index])`

Comment: @user3757279 I don't know what `channels_per_page` is. I'm guessing it's an integer, and the value of `channels_per_page` is larger than the number of items in `channelList`. You're taking small portions of my answer at a time, instead of the whole thing, and then of course it's going to break. How much about Python do you know?

Comment: well the `channels_per_page` is using for the integer to find the value of 7 channels, example: `abc family, CNN USA, ESPN USA, Fox News, Animal Planet, USA Network and SPIKE`. Hope that is clear to you? well i don't know about python alot but i'm still learning.

Comment: @user3757279 well instead of `range(0, channels_per_page)`, you should use `range(0, len(channelList))`, which is what was posted in the answer. That will ensure you don't go beyond the boundaries of the `channelList`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i can see it is working. I will get all of the list of every channels which i have 7 label controls and i want to get 7 channels using `range(0, len(channelList))`. how i could do that?

Comment: @user3757279 I literally wrote all of this in my answer above. Just use that code if you want to set the labels. It's fine if you don't know Python, but you really need to read everything we're writing.